# Basis of vector space of all polynomials degree 3 and lower.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Find two different bases for the vector space $W$ of all third and lower degree polynomials $g(x)$ satisfying $g(3)=0$.
Don't make the basis simply scalar multiples of the first basis.

Here is my solution

$$V_1 = \{(x-3),(x-3)^2,(x-3)^3\}\quad \quad 
V_2 = \{(3-x),x(3-x),x^2(3-x)\}$$

I am pretty sure that $V_1,V_2$ both span the polynomials with degree $3$ and lower, how should I go about showing that.  Also how do I show $V_1,V_2$ are not scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: Your feeling is right: does the constant polynomial $1$ have the value $0$ at $3$?

Comment: The space of polys of degree 3 or less is 4 dimensional. Imposing the single linear condition $g(3)=0$ cuts that down to 3 dim. So you have too many vectors in your bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes remove 1 from both the sets. This being a proper subspace, its dimension cannot be 4. Its dimension is 3. You can directly calculate and see that $a(x-3)^2\neq x(3-x)$ for any $a$ etc. (Assume such an equality is true and show that you cannot solve for $a$. This will lead to an inconsistent linear system. Same way for the next.

Also your second  basis can be proved to be a basis this way:

Fact: In polynomials with real coefficients the operation of multiplying them all by a fixed polynomial is an injective function: $f(x)g(x)=f(x)h(x)$ implies $g(x)=h(x)$ (with obvious exemptions). ALso this  operation is linear. That means the linearly independent set of polynomials  $\{1,x,x^2\}$ upon multiplication by $(3-x)$ will again be sent to a linearly independent set, and that is your second basis.

Comment: I am having trouble showing that a(x-1)^2=/=x(1-x).
ax^2-2ax+a=x-x^2
(a+1)x^2+(2a+1)x+a=0
When I apply quadratic formula I get x = (2a+1+-1)/(2a+2)

Comment: You don't solve for $x$; you are trying to see if two polynomials in $x$ are the same; that means whether they have same coefficients for every power of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You've learned lots of techniques for answering such questions about matrices — so turn the question into a problem about matrices. Express everything in coordinates relative to some basis (e.g. the power basis $1,x,x^2,x^3$), and note things like:

- $ g \mapsto g(3)$ is a linear transformation on $W$; in coordinates, it is multiplying on the right by the matrix
  $$ \left[ \begin{matrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 3^2 \\ 3^3 \end{matrix} \right] $$
- The coordinates of the elements of $V_1$ are the rows of the matrix, where I've used the symbol $\cdot$ for a matrix element whose value you don't actually care about.
  $$ \left[ \begin{matrix} \cdot & 1 & 0 & 0
  \\ \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0
  \\ \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$

(In the above, I used the convention of writing the coordinates of the elements of $W$ as row vectors. Using column vectors for this tends to be much more natural — however, you're probably more familiar with studying matrices in terms of row operations, and it's that part of the analysis that's important here, so I've used the opposite convention instead)